# Работа с Excel в Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Есть возможность из ехел файла

НАПРИМЕР(Номер дома|Номер квартиры|Номер телефона|Долг|)

А значения  : 1| 45 | 511224 | 500р| ( Все совпадения случайны)

И например :1| 17 | 306517| 150р | (таких строк допустим 20 всего).

Могу ли я вытянуть целую строку с екселя по номеру телефона например?
И если могу,буду очень рад увидеть пример.
Пытаюсь работать с Пандой,но ловлю ошибки

Comment: Или может можно без доставания всей строки ,сразу долг достать по номеру телефона?
так было вообще идеально)

Comment: Можете выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник Excel файл, содержащий несколько строк данных? Номера телефонов измените.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_excel(r'c:/temp/sample.xlsx', dtype={'Номер телефона':'str'})

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   Номер дома  Номер квартиры Номер телефона  Долг
0           1              45         511224  500р
1           1              17         306517  150р

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]:
Номер дома         int64
Номер квартиры     int64
Номер телефона    object
Долг              object
dtype: object

In [10]: df.loc[df['Номер телефона'] == '306517']
Out[10]:
   Номер дома  Номер квартиры Номер телефона  Долг
1           1              17         306517  150р
```

---

> как поменять долг 150р на 500 допустим? и оставить в той же строке

```
In [11]: df.loc[(df['Номер телефона']=='306517') & (df['Долг']=='150р'), 'Долг'] = '500р'

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   Номер дома  Номер квартиры Номер телефона  Долг
0           1              45         511224  500р
1           1              17         306517  500р
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо;)
А если не затруднит,подскажи пожалуйста,как поменять долг 150р на 500 допустим? и оставить в той же строке

Comment: А есть возможность достать конкретное значение и пихнуть его в переменную? а то у меня выходит достать только весь кусок целиком([0],[1]-а если вытаскивать по индексам,то ловлю ошибки)

Comment: @Pashka1122, я думаю лучше задать отдельный вопрос с небольшим примером данных и указать ошибку в вопросе...

Comment: Создал,если не затруднит,посмотри пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969041/excel-и-массив-python