# Excel и массив Python

Tags: python, массивы, excel, pandas

[image: Ексель]

```
        df = pd.read_excel(r'E:\PYTHON\exelbot\Образец_бот.xlsx', dtype={'Долг': 'str','Телефон1': 'str'})

        # print(df)
        a123 = df.loc[df['Телефон1'] == str(a)] # str(a) в данном случае это номер телефона 505808904

        print(a123.values) #этот принт выдает [[1 3 '505808904' nan nan 'АА1580ТЕ' nan nan nan '450']]
        a222 = str(a123.values)
        print(a222) # [[1 3 '505808904' nan nan 'АА1580ТЕ' nan nan nan '450']]
        print(len(a222)) #56
        if len(a222) == 2:
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id,'Такого номера нет')
            print('rabotaet')
        else:
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Долг : ' + a222[9])#выдает цифру 5из номера тел(505808904)
```

А проблемма заключается в том что: скрипт выдает цифру номера телефона, и почему то скобки массива работают не правильно (при индексе [ 1 ] -выводит [)

Тоесть переменная a222 вроде бы и отображается как масив,но возможно из-за модуля Panda ,не является массивом

Подскажите ,как можно достать поле долг (450) и поместить его в переменную abc например.

Comment: `a222` - строка, на это недвусмысленно намекает `a222 = str(a123.values)`. Элементы строки - символы (вообще-то односимвольные строки, но это не принципиально). Поэтому и `'5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
abc = df.loc[df['Телефон1'] == str(a)]['Долг'].values[0]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)